# Custom destination with RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rest, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ as a broker on my project and I want to assign the destination queue when I open the socket on the client side.
Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViTF5.png

I managed to do it with `SimpleBroker`, however when I try to do it with `StompBrokerRelay` I can't assing the queue on RabbitMQ and I stop receiving messages on the client (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BawYT.png).

This is how I'm doing it:

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class FeedController {

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations template;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/feed",  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public Reference getLeankrReference(@RequestBody Reference ref)
    {       
        this.template.convertAndSendToUser(ref.getChannelId(), "/topic/feed", ref);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

**Websocket configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
    {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/")
            .setAutoStartup(true);

        //config.enableSimpleBroker("/user/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/vision").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
        function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/ws/vision');
        var channel = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/' + channel + '/feed', function(message) {
                showContent(JSON.parse(message.body));
            });
        });
    }
```

I know that I'm missing something. Maybe some broker config?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Haven't you missed to configure `/queue/` alongside with `/topic/` ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I also tried `/queue/`. It helped me subscribe the queue on RabbitMQ. However, when I try to post something on the client, it doesn't receive any message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what I was missing!

**Websocket configuration:**

I was only assigning the *topic* queue. In this case, I need also the *queue* queue, once I want to assign it to a specific user/channel.

```
config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");
```

**Client:**

I wasn't referring the type of queue that I wanted to use.

`stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/feed', function(content) {`

But this was not enough. It was missing the correct security configuration.

Something like this,

**Security configuration:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .headers().addHeaderWriter(
            new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                    XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)).and()
        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html?logout")
            .logoutUrl("/logout.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("channel1").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

With that I added a login page. Which is not necessary. You just need to ensure that the password parameter is used for authentication.

Now that Rabbit knows the user/channel, it can send queues to specific destinations.